# Ensure a publisher is triggered exactly once with Reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

In a Reactor processing pipeline, a specific external REST API might be conditionally be invoked, depending on other external inputs.
Now, it is required to invoke this only once, though multiple different steps may require the output from this step.
It seems the Reactor can help with `Mono.cache()`, such that every subscriber will read the same output. I wonder if there's also a way to ensure that the specific API will invoked at most once with the help of some Reactor API.

The traditional solution could be to have a list of requestors for the API. Only the first requestor triggers the API invocation and then all of them wait for a notification when the result is ready.

With Reactor, the API to invoke at most once could naively be: `Mono<Response> invokeExternalApi(Request request);`. It could be invoked like so `.flatMap(r -> shouldInokeApi(o) ? client.invokeExternalApi(getRequest()) : Mono.just(null))`. However, the same step is needed in more than one place, which currently causes the API to be invoked multiple times.

Does Reactor support such functionality?

Comment: If you've got only one such request (or a few, identifiable statically), then you can just add a level of abstraction : create a *service* class with the cached Mono(s) as attribute(s). Then, instead of calling web client directly, pass by the *service* instance (which must therefore be long-living). In case the requests are built dynamically, then I think the question simplifies to: is there a by-key cache implementation compatible with reactor somewhere ?

Comment: Sounds like you advocate for the 'traditional solution'.
Since this seems to be commonly required and since Reactor is such a fundamental shift in paradigm and has the other half of the solution done, I was hoping it could aid in a solution here.